# Calling Webservice by NSURLConnection issues, Not called everytime?

Tags: http, ios5, webservice-client

I am calling .NET webservice hosted locally from my iPhone app (iOS5) like this:

```
(IBAction)btnCallService:(id)sender {
    [XYZActivity startAnimating];
    // So I could show activity on my main UI thread.
    [self performSelector: @selector(CallXYZSService) 
               withObject: nil 
               afterDelay: 0];
   }

 (void) CallXYZSService
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localwinhost/JSON_Service.asmx/GetFunction1"];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:1 timeoutInterval:30];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
    //[req setHTTPBody: [postStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (myConn) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
   }

}

}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
 NSLog(@"Service Failed");
}
```

Now my problem is sometimes it calls the service and I recive data , and sometimes it doesn'tand nothing happens.... not even timeout error...

What I am doing wrong here , I am calling my webservice asynch ... issue is it even doesn't go to any other delegate methods , just prepare the request , init the connection and then nothing happens....

Is it has something to do with previous connections to the webservice ? As for testing I am calling 2,3 different functions on same service on same server ... but these are happening on different viewcontrollers ...so I init new connection and set my connection to nil in connectionDidFinishLoading method.

Can any one plz help me here, how to make sure that I always get response back from service either valid response or some error.... or timeout....
If I test the same service on MAC in Safari , it always get called without any issue...!!!

Thanks, 
Maverick

---

I have changed the code as below

```
I have changed the code as below   NSString *jsonRequest_NE =    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID=%@&Password=%@",strID,strPwd];
NSString *jsonRequest =    [jsonRequest_NE stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

NSString *myURL = @"http://localwinhost/JSON_Service.asmx/GetFunction1";

NSString *fixedURL = [myURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but still the same beahviour, sometime it works sometimes it just doesn't..... 
I have searched alot...but still could't find proper solution... 
any one plz help me hereeeeeeeeeeee !!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any non-UFT8 characters in your jsonRequest variable.
Let me know how you managed it.

Comment: I am encoding everything properly ( I think ) but I m still getting the same issue of "Connection Lost" . FUnny thing is sometimes the same code works and I start getting proper responses and sometimes it doesn't at all.